# FluentValidation - validating across multiple properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

Have a form where a user can enter start date/time and end date/time for an event. Here's the validator so far:

```
public class EventModelValidator : AbstractValidator<EventViewModel>
    {
        public EventModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.StartDate)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Date is required!")
                .Must(BeAValidDate).WithMessage("Invalid date");
            RuleFor(x => x.StartTime)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Start time is required!")
                .Must(BeAValidTime).WithMessage("Invalid Start time");
            RuleFor(x => x.EndTime)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End time is required!")
                .Must(BeAValidTime).WithMessage("Invalid End time");
            RuleFor(x => x.Title).NotEmpty().WithMessage("A title is required!");
        }


        private bool BeAValidDate(string value)
        {
            DateTime date;
            return DateTime.TryParse(value, out date);
        }

        private bool BeAValidTime(string value)
        {
            DateTimeOffset offset;
            return DateTimeOffset.TryParse(value, out offset);
        }

    }
```

Now I'd also like to add validation that EndDateTime > StartDateTime (combined Date+Time properties), but not sure how to go about it.

**Edit:** 
To clarify, I need to somehow combine EndDate + EndTime/StartDate + StartTime i.e. DateTime.Parse(src.StartDate + " " + src.StartTime) and then validate EndDateTime vs. StartDateTime - how do I do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Finally got it working after I re-read the [documentation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators): *"Note that there is an additional overload for Must that also accepts an instance of the parent object being validated."*

```
public class EventModelValidator : AbstractValidator<EventViewModel>
    {
        public EventModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.StartDate)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Date is required!")
                .Must(BeAValidDate).WithMessage("Invalid date");
            RuleFor(x => x.StartTime)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Start time is required!")
                .Must(BeAValidTime).WithMessage("Invalid Start time");
            RuleFor(x => x.EndTime)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End time is required!")
                .Must(BeAValidTime).WithMessage("Invalid End time")
                // new
                .Must(BeGreaterThan).WithMessage("End time needs to be greater than start time");
            RuleFor(x => x.Title).NotEmpty().WithMessage("A title is required!");
        }


        private bool BeAValidDate(string value)
        {
            DateTime date;
            return DateTime.TryParse(value, out date);
        }

        private bool BeAValidTime(string value)
        {
            DateTimeOffset offset;
            return DateTimeOffset.TryParse(value, out offset);
        }
        // new
        private bool BeGreaterThan(EventViewModel instance, string endTime)
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(instance.StartDate + " " + instance.StartTime);
            DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(instance.EndDate + " " + instance.EndTime);
            return (DateTime.Compare(start, end) <= 0);
        }
    }
```

There might be a cleaner/more legant way to do this, but for now, it worksforme.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same client side ?

Comment: This is not valid anymore in FluentValitation. This is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20546097/59119

Answer (score 22):

You could could try using the `GreaterThan` rule:

```
RuleFor(x => x.EndDate)
    .GreaterThan(x => x.StartDate)
    .WithMessage("end date must be after start date");
```

Comment: Sorry, just added a clarification above. Need to combine Date + Time and **then** validate

Comment: Is it possible to do the same client side? or please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142489/how-to-validate-date-in-clientside-using-fluentvalidation