# FluentValidation rule for multiple properties

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a FluentValidator that has multiple properties like zip and county etc. I want to create a rule that takes two properties just like a RuleFor construct

```
public class FooArgs
{
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CountyId { get; set; }
}

public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<FooArgs>
{
    RuleFor(m => m.CountyId).Must(ValidZipCounty).WithMessage("wrong Zip County");
}
```

This works but I want to pass both Zip and county to the rue in order to validate. What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FluentValidation - validating across multiple properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701612/fluentvalidation-validating-across-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 107):

What about:

```
RuleFor(m => new {m.CountyId, m.Zip}).Must(x => ValidZipCounty(x.Zip, x.CountyId))
                                      .WithMessage("Wrong Zip County");
```

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: Elegant but how do you force this rule to evaluate?

Comment: It doesn't return information about which fields are incorrect.

Comment: You can use OverridePropertyName to set a property name.

Comment: While this seems to work, see @bpruitt-goddard's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20546097/2573109) for the canonical solution. This uses an overloaded version of the predicate validator to reference the parent object. https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#predicate-validator

Answer (score 90):

There is a `Must` overload that also provides you with the `FooArgs` object documented [here](https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators.html#predicate-validator). It allows you to easily pass both arguments into your method like this:

```
RuleFor(m => m.CountyId).Must((fooArgs, countyId) =>
    ValidZipCounty(fooArgs.Zip, countyId))
    .WithMessage("wrong Zip County");
```

Answer (score 42):

Just came across this old question and I think I have a simpler answer.  You can easily pass your whole object into your custom validation rule by simplifying the parameter to `RuleFor` e.g.

```
RuleFor(m => m).Must(fooArgs =>
    ValidZipCounty(fooArgs.Zip, fooArgs.countyId))
    .WithMessage("wrong Zip County");
```

If the `ValidZipCountry` method is local to your validator and you can change its signature to take a `FooArgs` then the code simplifies down to

```
RuleFor(m => m).Must(ValidZipCounty).WithMessage("wrong Zip County");
```

The only downside is that the `PropertyName` in the resultant validation error will be an empty string. This may cause a problem for you validation display code. However it is not really clear which property the error belongs too, `ContryId` or `Zip`, so this does make sense.

Comment: Just use the Must() overload that passes the whole object.

Comment: You can use `.WithName("FooArgs")` to eliminate the empty `PropertyName`.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I needed to mark a property as required (`x.RequiredProperty` in the example below) if another property was not null (`x.ParentProperty` in the example below). I ended up using the `When` syntax:

```
RuleFor(x => x.RequiredProperty).NotEmpty().When(x => x.ParentProperty != null);
```

Or if you have more then one rule for a common when clause you can write it as follows:

```cs
When(x => x.ParentProperty != null, () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.RequiredProperty).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.OtherRequiredProperty).NotEmpty();
});
```

The definition of the `When` syntax is the following:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Defines a condition that applies to several rules
/// </summary>
/// <param name="predicate">The condition that should apply to multiple rules</param>
/// <param name="action">Action that encapsulates the rules.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IConditionBuilder When (Func<T, bool> predicate, Action action);
```