# Validate case when model property is compared to another model property - FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation, fluent

I have model

```
public class DocProperty
{
    public int Size {get; set;}
    public int Volume {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

and I'm using FluentValidation

```
public class DocPropertyValidator: AbstractValidator<DocProperty>    
{
    public DocPropertyValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Size).Must(x => x < 1).WithMessage("Invalid Size!");
        RuleFor(a => a.Volume ).Must(x => x < 1).WithMessage("Invalid Volume!");            
    }
}
```

My question is:
How can I use FluentValidation and validate case when `Volume < Size`.

> In this case print Invalid case, volume cannot be less then Size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FluentValidation rule for multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529085/fluentvalidation-rule-for-multiple-properties)

Comment: `RuleFor(a => a.Volume).Must((dp, vol) => vol >= dp.Size).WithMessage("Volume cannot be less then Size")`;