# FluentValidation Validating Sums of Fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I have a number of fields I need to validate together. I need to check the sum of A+B+C = the sum of D+E.

If the sum of these two groups is not equal, I need to highlight all 5 fields. I can't seem to find a way to validate multiple properties together.

At [FluentValidation rule for multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529085/fluentvalidation-rule-for-multiple-properties) , @Matías Romero suggests using something like

```
RuleFor(m => new {m.CountyId, m.Zip}).Must(x => ValidZipCounty(x.Zip, x.CountyId))
                                  .WithMessage("Wrong Zip County");
```

This doesn't seem to highlight the invalid fields though. Is this possible with Fluent Validation (MVC5)?

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a custom validator check this link https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html